# How to pass a function as argument to other functions in order to avoid repeating code

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to implement `handleLocalStorage` into some other functions in order to avoid repeating code.

But how exactly can I pass the above mentioned function to other functions?

Any help is much appreciated.

```js
function handleLocalStorage() {
  let localTodos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
    localTodos = [];
  } else {
    localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  }
}

function saveTodos(todo) {
  // let localTodos;
  // if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
  //   localTodos = [];
  // } else {
  //   localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  // }

  localTodos.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("localTodos", JSON.stringify(localTodos));
}

function getTodos(todo) {
  // let localTodos;
  // if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
  //   localTodos = [];
  // } else {
  //   localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  // }

  localTodos.forEach(function(todo) {
    const newTodoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newTodoDiv.classList.add("todo");

    const todoTitle = document.createElement("li");
    todoTitle.innerText = todo;
    todoTitle.classList.add("todo-item");
    newTodoDiv.appendChild(todoTitle);

    const checkedBtn = document.createElement("button");
    checkedBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='far fa-check-square'></i>";
    checkedBtn.classList.add("checked-btn");
    newTodoDiv.appendChild(checkedBtn);

    const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    delBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>";
    delBtn.classList.add("del-btn");
    newTodoDiv.appendChild(delBtn);

    todoList.appendChild(newTodoDiv);
  });
}

function clearTodos(todo) {
  // let localTodos;
  // if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
  //   localTodos = [];
  // } else {
  //   localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  // }

  const todoIndex = todo.children[0].innerText;
  localTodos.splice(localTodos.indexOf(todoIndex), 1);
  localStorage.setItem("localTodos", JSON.stringify(localTodos));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass a function as an arguemnt to an another function?

Comment: `otherFunc(handleLocalStorage)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass functions to parameters of other functions. For example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
}

function bar(functionParam) {
  functionParam();
  console.log("bar");
}

bar(foo); // The console output is `foo\nbar`
```

However, I think this will not help you. You can simply use function calls to achieve the effect you want. Like so:

```js
function getLocalTodos() {
  let localTodos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
    localTodos = [];
  } else {
    localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  }
  return localTodos;
}

function saveTodos(todo) {
  let localTodos = getLocalTodos();

  localTodos.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("localTodos", JSON.stringify(localTodos));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a function as a parameter to another function, this is usually referred to as ["callback functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

first i would make the `handleLocalStorage` function return the localTodos value:

```
function handleLocalStorage() {
  const localTodos = localStorage.getItem("localTodos");
  if (localTodos === null) {
    return [];
  }

  return JSON.parse(localTodos);
}
```

then add another argument to your function's signature and then call this argument (like you call a function)

```
function saveTodos(getLocalTodos, todo) {
  const localTodos = getLocalTodos();
  ... //rest of code
```

then just send it as an argument:

```
saveTodos(handleLocalStorage, todo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have handleLocalStorage return localTodos instead of passing it to other functions and simply call it where it is needed.

```
function handleLocalStorage() {
  let localTodos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("localTodos") === null) {
    localTodos = [];
  } else {
    localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodos"));
  }
  return localTodos;
}


function saveTodos(todo) {
  let localTodos = handleLocalStorage();
  localTodos.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("localTodos", JSON.stringify(localTodos));
}
```

P.S. In javascript, if you need to pass function to a different function, you can simply pass it like you would any other argument.

```
function funcA(){return 10;}
function funcB(fun){console.log(fun());}
funcB(funcA);
//logs 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let funcA = function () { 
    console.log("Hello from funcA"); 
}
let funcB = function(funcAsArgument, otherArgument) {
    funcAsArgument();
    console.log("Other Argument: ", otherArgument);
}

funcB(funcA, "Dummy Argument") //Passing funcA() as argument to funcB

// Prints
// Hello from funcA
// Other Argument:  Dummy Argument
//
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a function as an argument to an another function, you can specify the name of function as the argument.

**Working Example**

```js
function handleLocalStorage() {
  console.log('Inside handleLocalStorage function');
}

function saveTodos(listner) {
  //listner is handleLocalStorage function
  console.log('Inside saveTodos function');
  console.log('clearTodos saveTodos calls handleLocalStorage');
  listner();
}

function getTodos(listner1, listner2) {
  //listner1 is saveTodos function
  //listner2 is saveTodos handleLocalStorage
  console.log('Inside getTodos function');
  console.log('clearTodos getTodos calls saveTodos');
  listner1(listner2);
}

function clearTodos(todo) {
  console.log('Inside clearTodos function');
  console.log('clearTodos function calls getTodos');
  getTodos(saveTodos, handleLocalStorage);
}

clearTodos();
```